# Auto-submit of form via jquery of a jsp file submits form automatically but the page is reloading forever

Tags: jquery, forms, jsp

This line of code make form-submitting forever reloading:

```
$(function () {$('#submit').click();
                    });
```

I tried the following scripts inside the body but they do not fix my problem. This line cannot fix it also:

```
<script> document.forms.ekek.submit(); </script>
```

This doesn't work also:

```
<script> document.forms['ekek'].submit(); </script>
```

And also this one:

```
<script> document.getElementById('ekek').submit(); </script>
```

How do I fix it? Here is the complete JSP code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.1.js">
        </script>
        <title>JSP Sample Auto-Submit via Jquery</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>sample Auto-Submit via JQuery</h1>
        <form action="ekek.jsp" method="POST" name="ekek" id="ekek">
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="Allan" />
            <input type ="submit" name="tosubmit" id="submit" `value="Submit">`
        </form>
        <div id="sample"></div>
        <script>
            $(function () {$('#submit').click();
                });
        </script>
        <%
           if (request.getParameter("tosubmit")!=null)
           {
             out.print("<script>document.getElementById('sample').innerHTML = '"+request.getParameter("hiddenname")+"';</script>");
           }
        %>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You want to fire the click when an event happens. when do you exactly want the form to be posted? like when the user clicks `submit` or when the value of an input field changes. what is that event? when you know that, you can bind the `click` on submit to be triggered when that even occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This function submit the form every time when your page is reloaded. So this wont work.

```
 $(function () {$('#submit').click();});
```

You need to explain the purpose of submitting this form. If you want your form to be submitted when page loads then do it with ajax. Or submit the form on some action like button click.

Comment: I will use the code fragment of auto-submit form to a verification page. That page will produce no output. It will act as redirection page. That page will have a condition and if that condition is satified, it will auto-submit the form. If the condition is not satisfied, it will display an alert message then it will go back to the previous page.

Comment: Do this with Ajax

Answer (score 0):

I finally understand what happened here. I forgot something that's why it became a logical error. I was just testing the code whether it will auto-submit the form via JQuery. And it did. My error was, the form was submitting to itself, and the page forcefully click the submit button and then output the hidden content below the button and repeat the process all over again. The solution to this is to change the form action into a different page and then move the *div* part into that page and also move the code below to that other page as stated in form action:

```
if (request.getParameter("tosubmit")!=null)
{
out.print("<script>document.getElementById('sample').innerHTML = '"+request.getParameter("hiddenname")+"'</script>");
}
```

When I did that, it forwarded to my second.jsp as I change *action="ekek.jsp"* to *action="second.jsp"*, and it stopped reloading. I was laughing when I found the solution.